# Android problem changing app language programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, locale

I've built an android application (using Xamarin c#) and it contains a Settings screen where users can change app language.
This language setting is saved also on the server by calling an API.
After changing the language I refresh texts into the settings screen and into other opened activities and all seems work.

The problem is when I close and reopen the app: I sign in the user and I read language data from the server.
I programmatically change the locale language of the app into my main activity: for example, I set a language different than the default smartphone language.
This activity contains 4 fragments into a ViewPager, but sometimes these fragments are in the "old" language and "new" language is not correctly applied.
So, when I open a new activity, the language shown is the "old" and not the "new".

Am I doing something wrong?
Can anyone help me?

Following my code:

In my AppBaseActivity class, OnCreate event:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);

if (UserSettings != null
    && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserSettings.LanguageCode))
{
    LocaleManager.ChangeAppLanguage(this, UserSettings.LanguageCode);
}
```

In my AppBaseActivity class, OnResume event:

```
base.OnResume();

if (UserSettings != null
    && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserSettings.LanguageCode))
{
    LocaleManager.ChangeAppLanguage(this, UserSettings.LanguageCode);
}
```

My LocaleManager.ChangeAppLanguage method:

```
public static bool ChangeAppLanguage(Context context, String lang, bool saveInSharedPreferences)
        {
            Locale newLocale = new Locale(lang);

            if (Locale.Default.Language != newLocale.Language)
            {
                Locale.Default = newLocale;
                Android.Content.Res.Configuration config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration();

                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                {
                    config.SetLocale(newLocale);
                }
                else
                {
                    config.Locale = newLocale;
                }

                context.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

                if (saveInSharedPreferences)
                    return Helper.SaveInSharedPreferences(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".languageCode", lang);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should load the new `Context` in the  `AttachBaseContext` method of your AppBaseActivity,you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469439/10768653)